# Android: Activity showing extra space at bottom when padding 0dp - Related to json?

Tags: android, json, scrollview, padding

I have an activity that shows extra space at the bottom even though I have no bottom padding applied. Style code, xml code, java code and a screenshot are below and the relevant json data is here:

http://lara.rufflecol.es/strollcharlton/strollcharlton_data_1_2.json

It isn't a huge issue it is just annoying! Have already tried to using android:fillViewport set as true or false but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is the problem related to my json?

UsefulLinks.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/dark_green"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/useful_links"
            style="@style/UsefulLinksTextStyling"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="UsefulLinksTextStyling" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fifteen_size</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
</style>
```

UsefulLinks.java

```
TextView usefulLinksIntroTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.useful_links);
usefulLinksIntroTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.getUsefulLinks()));     
usefulLinksIntroTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PK6x.png)

Comment: try changing ScrollView height to match parent

Comment: no different but thanks

Comment: Try using the uiautomatorview tool which is located in the sdk/tools/ folder.  It might give you an idea of which item the padding is part of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ensure the html that you are setting to the textview does not having blank space inside of it

change your base `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` so that if the html takes up less than the screen height you don't have "extra padding"

You can also turn on "show layout bounds" for your application, that way you will understand which View is giving you the "extra padding" http://tysmith.me/post/27035355999/layoutbounds combine it with the Hierarchy Viewer http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/index.html to work out which View is at fault